# ZEND Gdata Uncaught Exception

Tags: php, google-docs-api, zend-framework2, google-sheets-api

Have recently rebuild Apache after which G Data API stopped working, here is the error I'm getting:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Gdata_App_Exception' with message 'DOMDocument cannot parse XML: ' in /home/location/ZendGdata-1.7.1/library/Zend/Gdata/App.php:720 Stack trace: #0 /home/location/ZendGdata-1.7.1/library/Zend/Gdata/App.php(688): Zend_Gdata_App::importString('importUrl('http://spreadsh...', 'Zend_Gdata_Spre...') #2 /home/location/ZendGdata-1.7.1/library/Zend/Gdata.php(149): Zend_Gdata_App->getFeed('http://spreadsh...', 'Zend_Gdata_Spre...') #3 /home/location/ZendGdata-1.7.1/library/Zend/Gdata/Spreadsheets.php(141): Zend_Gdata->getFeed('http://spreadsh...', 'Zend_Gdata_Spre...') #4 /home/location/auto-post2gdoc.php(41): Zend_Gdata_Spreadsheets->getSpreadsheetFeed() #5 {main} thrown in /home/location/ZendGdata-1.7.1/library/Zend/Gdata/App.php on line 720

The new build has follow config for dom:

```
dom
DOM/XML enabled
DOM/XML API Version 20031129
libxml Version  2.7.8
HTML Support    enabled
XPath Support   enabled
XPointer Support    enabled
Schema Support  enabled
RelaxNG Support enabled
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out magicquotes was the culprit!

Answer (score 0):

Download latest version of [Zend_Gdata](http://framework.zend.com/downloads/latest#ZF1) - 1.12.0
I was having some problems with analytics API and reason was Google switched off older API version.

Comment: Thanks for the information, Just tried what you said, no luck.

Comment: Ok, then would be good to know what is the response, if it's not xml then probably error message I guess.

Comment: Is there a way I can check that?

Comment: Xdebug - switch on debugging and see what's going on. 
I would say Zend_Http_Client is place where to look.